Zitadel Go API, inconsistent auth context
I've recreated the Zitadel- Go API tutorial from quickstart, and most of the time it works correctly, however I have noticed some inconsistency.
For example in this code snippet:
router.Handle("/api/tasks", mw.RequireAuthorization()(http.HandlerFunc(
        func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            // Using the [middleware.Context] function we can gather information about the authorized user.
            // This example will just print the users ID using the provided method, and it will also
            // print the username by directly access the field of the typed [*oauth.IntrospectionContext].
            authCtx := mw.Context(r.Context())
            slog.Info("user accessed task list", "id", authCtx.UserID(), "username", authCtx.Username)

            // Although this endpoint is accessible by any authorized user, you might want to take additional steps
            // if the user is granted a specific role. In this case an `admin` will be informed to add a new task:
            list := tasks
            if authCtx.IsGrantedRole("admin") {
                list = append(list, "create a new task on /api/add-task")
            }

            // return the existing task list
            err = jsonResponse(w, &taskList{Tasks: list}, http.StatusOK)
            if err != nil {
                slog.Error("error writing response", "error", err)
            }
        })))

Sometimes it works correctly and I receive the empty list, however after every couple requests I get denied with the same request saying that I'm unauthorized:
token introspection failed: http status not ok: 400 Bad Request {"error":"unauthorized_client"}

I'm using a Service User with PAT for testing, what can cause this inconsistency?

Going by the code you showed (which IMO is insufficient to diagnose anything), I just had a quick look at the zitadel-go repo, and found this issue from a couple of weeks/months ago: https://github.com/zitadel/zitadel-go/issues/299
This does seem like something you might want to dig in to

The whole code is copy-pasted from the tutorial from the Zitadel docs available here
https://zitadel.com/docs/examples/secure-api/go
Thanks, I will check out the issue, although I'd like re-invent/workaround as little as possible

Well, the person who reported the issue commented that they've implemented a workaround, and the response was that the workaround essentially "will have to do for now" as the creator(s) didn't have time to fix it (at least, that's what it looked like to me)
